# HTTP-Live-Streaming - Loading Issue?

Tags: iphone, streaming, ios4, http-live-streaming

I'm (trying) to use HTTP-Live-Streaming in my app and after weeks of re-encoding it seems to work now without errors by the mediastream validator.

On my latest iPod Touch (iOS 4.0) with WiFi the videostream loads in 1sec and switches to the highest bandwidth stream.
On another test device iPhone 3G (iOS 3.0) with WiFi it takes up to 30 seconds to load the stream - although I see in my log files that it looks for the high quality stream after 1 second. But I get a black screen with audio only in the first 30 seconds. Is this problem to due the better CPU on the latest iPod touch or is it due to the iOS upgrade?

Also I'm fearing another rejection by Apple because the last time they checked my stream they only looked at each videostream for about 3 seconds and then rejected because they didn't see any video.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the segmented files.  Example: can you play the first low-quality MPEG-TS segment in VLC?  Is their video there?

I've found iOS devices to be very picky about that they will and won't play.  Make sure you are using a lowest common denominator code settings.  I'm a big fan of [The Complete Guide to iPod, Apple TV and iPhone Video Formats](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-ipod-video-formats-and-display-resolutions/)